Can Kotlin deserialize multiple JSON formats to a single class?
I have a Kotlin class representing some control data:
@Serializable(with = ControlSerializer::class)
class ControlData(
    val start: Double,
    val end: Double,
    val offset: Double?,
    val ramp: Double?,
)

Which should be deserialized from one of two JSON formats:
{ "control": {
    "start": 0.5,
    "end": 1.0,
    "offset": 3.0,
    "ramp": 2.0
    }
}

or
{ "control": 2.0 }

In the second format, the single float value should be expanded into start and end, with offset and ramp set to null.
I managed to get this to work using a JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer that selects a specific serializer based on the JSON type, but as the default serializer is not generated I needed to reimplement it:
object ControlSerializer: JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer(ControlData::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(content: JsonElement) {
        return when(content) {
            is JsonPrimitive -> FloatSerializer
            is JsonObject -> ObjectSerializer
            else -> throw Exception("Unrecognized data type")
        }
    }
}

object FloatSerializer: KSerializer<ControlData> {
    // Removed for brevity, but simple serialize/deserialize methods that use encodeDouble()
    // and decodeDouble()
}

object ObjectSerializer: KSerializer<ControlData> {
    // Also removed for brevity, but a more complicated class that uses
    // CompositeDecoder.decodeElementIndex to manually extract every element, which feels
    // unnecessarily complicated when the serialization package normally handles this by default
}

My question now is twofold:

Is there a way to access the default serializer for a class after setting up a custom serializer, so I don't have to reimplement it manually?
In deference to the XY problem, is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I suspect there may be, but I haven't been able to figure out what it might be.

Ideally I'd like the logic to be contained within the serializers so I don't have to construct a custom Json object, but I realise this may not be possible. Currently I only need to deserialize data.
Thank you!

It looks like there is a github issue for this exact request: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1169
So afaict in the next release (2.0.20) of kotlin(x) there should be support to still generate the default serializer, by tagging the class with @KeepGeneratedSerializer and using it in your deserializer using .generatedSerializer().
As for the current version, your solution is fine, an ugly-ish alternative would be to create a private ControlDataDummy that is also @Serializable and identical, you then delegate the deserialization to the default serializer of the dummy and then convert it to ControlData. The linked issue also contains a similar workaround that does it maybe a bit more elegant with a typealias: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/840#issuecomment-1674907335
